# Delete dynamic array of pointers containing duplicates

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates, delete-operator

What's the correct way to free the memory here?
The pointer-array contains duplicates!

```
class HashTable
{
   Bucket<E>** index = new Bucket<E>*[indexSize];
   ...
}

~ExtHash( ) 
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < indexSize; ++i) 
     delete index[i];

   delete[] index;
 }
```

Comment: By duplicates you mean pointers to the same elements?

Comment: yes, like this index[0] --> 0x123, index[1] --> 0x456, index[2] --> 0x123

Comment: Isn't C++ robust to this automatically?

Comment: @Tomas: No; if you destroy an object, then any pointer or reference to that object becomes a live hand grenade. Deleting an object twice (as this code would do) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Well, it can't be 100% robust, but just by storing some sequence of bytes that is unlikely to happen... I think C++ could be able to be 99.99% robust :-)

Comment: @Tomas: Well, it doesn't in any implementation I know of (except maybe some debug builds); and this wouldn't help if the memory has been reallocated. Tools like Valgrind can help find this error, but you certainly can't rely on the C++ runtime to detect and fix it. C++ is generally designed to avoid the need for implicit runtime checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a set to remove duplicates:

```
std::set<Bucket*> uniqueBuckets(index, index + indexSize);

for(Bucket* bucket: uniqueBuckets)
    delete bucket;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would think hard about whether you want this container to be responsible for deleting the objects; it would be simpler to store them elsewhere, and just use this container to refer to them, not to manage their lifetimes.

Alternatively, you could use `std::shared_ptr` to manage the objects; then they will be deleted automatically when you've discarded all of them.

If you really want to do it this way, you'll need to remove the duplicates after deleting each one; something like

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < indexSize; ++i) {
    Bucket<E> * victim = index[i];
    indexSize = std::remove(index+i+1, index+indexSize, victim) - index;
    delete victim;
}
```

[NOTE: this code may well be wrong; I certainly made a couple of mistakes writing it. If you really want to manage dynamic objects the hard way, then you'll need to test it thoroughly]

Answer (score 2):

Sort `index`, remove adjacent duplicates with `std::unique`. O(N log N) and that's as good as it gets.

Comment: Yes, that's more efficient and less error prone than the dodgy code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation it's dangerous to store raw pointers in such way. Better use std::shared_ptr and just reset shared pointers. And after all pointers will be reseted they will be safely freed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

```
~ExtHash( ) 
{
  std::sort(index, index + indexSize);
  size_t new_end = std::unique(index, index + indexSize) - index;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < new_end; ++i) 
     delete index[i];

   delete[] index;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you create a pointer, `push_back` it into a vector. That vector will hold all your created pointers, and will hold each one of them only once.

Later, iterate that vector and `delete` the pointers.
It's like writing your own simple garbage collector.

Comment: Alternatively, keep the objects themselves in a list (not a vector, since you want pointers to them to remain valid as more are added). Then you won't need `new` and `delete` at all; the list will automatically destroy them for you.